# Unable to access req.files in nodeJS with express 4.0 when using a router

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file-upload, express

When I try to upload a file to my server, it fails with this error :

```
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
   at router.get.files (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/controllers/index.js:229:29)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at ensureAuthenticated (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/controllers/index.js:210:39)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (/home/n07070/Documents/Code/PicTemp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

I have my app.js in two parts :
A file called index.js in ./controllers/ and a file called app.js in the master directory. I call the index.js in the app.js like this :`

```
// Load the controller
var index = require('./controllers/index');
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer({dest:'./writable/'}).single('file'));


app.use('/', index);
```

And in app.js,

```
module.exports = router;

router.post('/upload', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var is;
    var os;
    var targetPath;
    var targetName;
    console.log(req.files);
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path;
    //get the mime type of the file
    var type = mime.lookup(tempPath);
    //get the extenstion of the file
    var extension = tempPath.split(/[. ]+/).pop();

    //check to see if we support the file type
    if (IMAGE_TYPES.indexOf(type) == -1) {
      return res.send(415, 'Supported image formats: jpeg, jpg, jpe, png.');
    }

    //create a new name for the image
    targetName = uid(22) + '.' + extension;

    //determine the new path to save the image
    targetPath = path.join(TARGET_PATH, targetName);

    //create a read stream in order to read the file
    is = fs.createReadStream(tempPath);

    //create a write stream in order to write the a new file
    os = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);

    is.pipe(os);

    //handle error
    is.on('error', function() {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(500, 'Something went wrong');
      }
    });

    //if we are done moving the file
    is.on('end', function() {

      //delete file from temp folder
      fs.unlink(tempPath, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(500, 'Something went wrong');
        }

        //send something nice to user
        res.render('image', {
          name: targetName,
          type: type,
          extension: extension
        });

      });//#end - unlink
    });//#end - on.end
});
```

I use mutler to handle file uploads.
How could I fix this ? Thank you.

Comment: There is no `req.files.file`, if you have multiple files `req.files` would be an array, and the files would be accessed with `req.files[0]`

Comment: I only have one file, so I guess it would be just req.file ?

Comment: Indeed it would ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @adeneo, `req.files` is an array when you have multiples files.

You need to access those by bringing it up as `req.files[x]`.